# Skip document loading when Visual Studio starts up

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When Visual Studio 2010 starts up it sometimes freezes when loading documents that were previously opened when I had the solution open last. I have to end the process in Task Manager  and reopen it. When I reopen it, it skips document loading and says this in the Output window:

> An error was encountered while opening associated documents the last
>   time this solution was loaded. Document load is being skipped during
>   this solution load in order to avoid that error.

My question is, is there an argument (or a setting) I can use when opening Visual Studio that will force document loading to be skipped? That way I won't have to open VS and wait for it to freeze before killing it and opening it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Startup
```

And select start page instead of opening last solution.

To prevent files opening when loading a solution (which is probably what you ask about), just delete the `.user` file in the projetcs directory -- this resets your local setting of which files are open on solution load.